# get table size from named database

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres I know how to select the size of a database ->

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('b2049623_data'));
```

I know how to select the size of a table

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('image_table'));
```

but multiple databases in my postgres will a table named 'image_table' how do I specify that I want the tableSize of image_table from a particular datbase?

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('image_table'));
```

returns 1688kb but the table size is 8192 bytes and the toast table size is 1656...where is the difference coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_table_size` returns the size of the database you're currently connected to. You cannot connect to one database and query the size of a table in a different database, even if it resides on the same server.

Comment: thanks for reply @mureinik...please see update of post